# I have accidentally posted answer for question A, to question B. Is there a way to safely and permanently remove it?

Tags: support

Is there a way to **really** (permanently) delete this answer? I don't like having a *pseudo* deleted post, which has an *Undelete* button, and the sole reason for this is a sanity. I just like keeping my stuff clean and without unnecessary data stashed in.

I hope that no penalty is given on this. I immediately removed the answer.

Comment: You haven't explained _why_ you don't like a pseudo-deleted post. This is default on Stack Overflow, true deletions are only for very, very rare exceptions.

Comment: I just asked a question *whether it is possible*. Reason: I just wish to keep the pile clean, where no unnecessary deleted stuff gets stashed.. even though I don't have much, still, I love cleanness.

Comment: Technically yes, but it's impractical to use for non-emergency circumstances.

Comment: @KevinB technically - sure. :) but how real and simple it is to ask for it? - is effectively my question. So, I'll let it stay how it is. I suppose no any consequences or drawbacks would follow this, and it will just stay like it is as if it doesn't exist.

Comment: What else can I have a reason? it's just completely irrelevant to that question. *Custom mod tag* you mean to flag it as to report to a moderator? and then I should ask the moderator to contact SE Employee..? am I getting this right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to actually delete deleted post that is only hidden?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390956/is-it-possible-to-actually-delete-deleted-post-that-is-only-hidden)

Comment: @DavyM well, initially I thought it does (it reads similar), but the answers doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri A good reason would be, for example, if you''d be working at a defense contractor and accidentally posted top secret nuclear weapon designs instead of an answer. Think in that order, rather than _I'd just like it deleted for cleanliness_. Anything where leaving the content pseudo-deleted would be actively harmful and illegal. And even then, they might remove the body instead of the entire answer.

Comment: There is a way that you could get it hidden completely from your own view, but I don't think you'll like it. Make a new account, and never gain more than 10,000 rep. Then you won't ever have the privilege that allows you to view that answer.

Answer (score 8):

While it’s possible for posts to be hard deleted, this requires employee time. Because of this, it’s only done in very special cases. (I can’t really think of a good example of this; I think that the very first “questions” on Stack Overflow may have been hard deleted.)

Asking for hard deletion for an answer that you meant to post on a different question will not be granted. Hard deletion of the post wouldn’t even be done if you “[accidentally posted top secret nuclear weapon designs instead of an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400659/i-have-accidentally-posted-answer-for-question-a-to-question-b-is-there-a-way#comment792041_400659)”: that would be *redaction*, which keeps the post, simply replacing or removing any sensitive information, and it requires two moderators to do. Asking for redaction of a post to remove information that isn’t sensitive would not be done either.

If you’re looking to keep the list of deleted answers on a question clean (visible only to 10k+ rep users), then I suggest editing your deleted answer to say something like “posted here by accident”. This keeps it short to minimize the amount of scrolling past needed and makes it not seem so suspicious that a lot of people would feel the need to check the revision history.

(Also, I don’t see it likely that this deleted answer would count against you in any way, as at your reputation it would probably be impossible to accidentally trigger an answer ban.)

Comment: Deletion by an employee [seems to be completely out of the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/152921/3).